# VerifyError: Error #1107: The ABC data is corrupt, attempt to read out of bounds. - Flash CS5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash-cs5

I tested this flash application in Flash IDE, it never through this error. But When I uploaded in server, got this error. Why we getting this VerifyError? It is a flash application loads all the library assets through bulk loader, later it will get assets from bulkloader to display in the main page. Assets includes swf,xml etc.

Comment: Definitly need more info. And a question to answer! Don't why this question would get an up vote.

Comment: @TandemAdam . I tested this flash application in Flash IDE, it never through this error. But When I uploaded in server, got this error. Why we getting this VerifyError? It is a flash application loads all the library assets through bulk loader, later it will get assets from bulkloader to display in the main page.

Comment: @Florian library assets includes swf,xml etc.

Comment: I think the problem comes from a SWF you're loading. Try to find which one is responsible forst

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens when loading external SWF files, which are using a different version of classes that are in the main application.

This could be because you compiled some RSL's, modules or other external SWF against a different version of the Flex SDK. It could also be that you changed a class and didn't recompile all of the SWF's again.

Sometimes you can do everything right, but an old SWF is cached by your browser, and so is incompatible with your main application. You can get around this by adding the version number to file names, so that an old cached version is never used.